# Reusable way to put a bright red box around whatever element currently has focus?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got some windows with mainly comboboxes, textboxes, and checkboxes. When you click on one to get focus I need a way to have them be outlined with a colorful box (boss' orders). Is there a way to do this easier than overriding the default style of all of these controls? I've never done that before, so it would take a lot of mucking around on my part to figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try adding a [FocusVisualStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613567.aspx) to the Controls that need different focus rectangle styles.

From above link

> The second mechanism is to provide a separate style as the value of the [FocusVisualStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.focusvisualstyle.aspx) property; the "focus visual style" creates a separate visual tree for an adorner that draws on top of the control, rather than changing the visual tree of the control or other UI element by replacing it.

Something like this in your Window's Xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="NewFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border>
                        <Rectangle Stroke="Red"  Margin="2" StrokeThickness="1"  StrokeDashArray="1 2" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

or your Application.Xaml file.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="NewFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border>
                        <Rectangle Stroke="Red"  Margin="2" StrokeThickness="1"  StrokeDashArray="1 2" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

**Usage:**

```
<ComboBox FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource NewFocusVisual}"  Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="238,102,0,0" Name="ComboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
<CheckBox FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource NewFocusVisual}" Content="CheckBox" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="238,71,0,0" Name="CheckBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
<TextBox FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource NewFocusVisual}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="238,144,0,0" Name="TextBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
```

---

If you want the Focus rectangle to change for every type of focus event Microsoft states that:

> From Microsoft:  Focus visual styles act exclusively for keyboard focus. As such, focus visual styles are a type of accessibility feature. If you want UI changes for any type of focus, whether via mouse, keyboard, or programmatically, then you should not use focus visual styles, and should instead use setters and triggers in styles or templates that are working from the value of general focus properties such as IsFocused or IsFocusWithin.

---

Give this a shot it works for a TextBox haven't checked your other Controls

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" >
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Control.BorderBrush" Value="Red"  />
                <Setter Property="Control.BorderThickness" Value="3" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: A little confused, where would I put the <Window.Resources>... bit? In app.xaml?

Comment: @cost It would go in the Application.Resources area in the Application.xaml file. I was meaning you could put that code in your Window's Xaml file or the Application's Xaml file. See Code edit. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Ahh okay, I get it now, thank you. Unfortunately, I put it in app.xaml and in my textbox markup, but it doesn't have any affect. Any idea why?

Comment: @cost It appears it works for Keyboard intiated focus change only, it is disable if you use a mouse or progamically do it. Am looking for an alternative.

Comment: That is a very peculiar limitation. I really appreciate your help with this though

Comment: The only way I can think to sort of do this (short of using a special rectangle for every control) is to have a FocusChanged triggered method that changed whatever control currently has focus to have a borderbrush color of red.

Comment: @cost that is what I was looking at, the problem is accessing the BorderBrush since it is part of the ControlTemplate.

Comment: I was able to almost do it by having a focus changed event, just casting the args as a Control type, and changing Control.Borderbrush to a red line. But it still doesn't show up because the textbox has a focused color it gets that overrides the usual borderbrush. I need to find what to change to change that