# Highlight a WPF control when it gets focus

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

I am working on a WPF application having lots of screens and every screen has lots of controls on it.
It becames very difficult to determine which control has focus.

So i want to highlight the control that currently have focus on it. It could be textbox, button, combobox, listbox or grid.

It'll be better if we could do this using styles and triggers.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use a trigger for the right event. In your case it's `IsFocused`. Simple example:

```
<Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
</Trigger>
```

You should use a `Style` tag, if you want to apply this style for a **particular** control type (use `TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"`, for example).

If you want to apply to **all control** types in your application, than you should consider using a base style with only such kind of trigger and than just inherit it in your custom styles with a help of `BasedOn` attribute: 
`<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseFocusStyle}">`

Good example of how to do this is a SO question: "[How to make Style.Triggers trigger a different named style to be applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183982/wpf-how-to-make-style-triggers-trigger-a-different-named-style-to-be-applied)".

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using visual states in custom styles for every control. All standard controls will suport this visual state. For example check out the MSDN style for [button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328) you will notice there is a visual state for Focused. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903963%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) MSDN article might also help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try and create an [adorner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx) for this behavior; in case you are open to use 3'rd party open source library then have a look at this implementation on codeplex, you can also go through the code to get idea about how to implement your own adorner -

http://uiannotations.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Adorners&referringTitle=Documentation

> [image]

Another similar question having details about other solutions - [Reusable way to put a bright red box around whatever element currently has focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10771504/reusable-way-to-put-a-bright-red-box-around-whatever-element-currently-has-focus)